# retrofit загрузить картинку

Tags: kotlin, vkontakte-api, retrofit, upload

интерфейсы для получения ссылки из vkapi и загрузки картинки

```
// получение ссылки для загрузки фото
    @GET("photos.getOwnerPhotoUploadServer?")
    fun getUrlUpload(
        @Query("access_token") access_token : String = token,
        @Query("v") version : String = VKVERSION,
        @Query("owner_id") owner_id : String
    ) : Call<VKUrlUploadResponse>

    // загрузка аватарки
    @Multipart
    @POST("{url}")
    fun setUrlUpload(
        @Path("url") url : String,
        @Part("photo") photo : RequestBody?
    ) : Response<ResponseBody>
```

Далее вызываю метод

```
        CommonVk.vkService.getUrlUpload(owner_id = "-${group?.id}").enqueue(object : Callback<VKUrlUploadResponse>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<VKUrlUploadResponse>, throwable: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<VKUrlUploadResponse>, response: Response<VKUrlUploadResponse>) {
                (response.body() as VKUrlUploadResponse).response?.upload_url.let {
                    url = it.toString()
                    println("url = $url")
                }
                var file = File(iconSourceFile)
                var body  = (file).asRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                CommonVk.vkService.setUrlUpload(url = url, photo = body)

            }
        })
```

Выходит вот такая ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>
    for method VkService.setUrlUpload
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:116)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.setUrlUpload(Unknown Source)
    at ru.Frozik6k.VKmonitoring.app.vkapi.VkClient$createGroup$1$onResponse$3.onResponse(vkTestService.kt:80)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>.
  Tried:
   * retrofit2.CompletableFutureCallAdapterFactory
   * retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:272)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:114)
    ... 11 more
```